# Invalid Prop for Model Name, String Input presented as 'Undefined'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my SelectedAttribute.vue component I'm receiving this error:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "modelName". Expected String, got Undefined
```

However I can't see why I'm receiving this error, as I provide a String in response. I'll attach my relevant code below.

InternalTable.vue

```
 <b-table-column v-if="" field="columnName" v-slot="itemProps">
          <SelectableAttribute
              :attr-name="props2.row.fieldClass"
              :attr-id="itemProps.row.id"
              :model-id="props.row.id"
              :model-name="NewParticipant"
          >
            {{ itemProps.row.value }}
          </SelectableAttribute>
        </b-table-column>
```

SelectedAttributes.vue

```
  props: {
attrName: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
attrId: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
},
modelName: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
modelId: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
},


 },
```

Comment: What is the value of `NewParticipant`? Maybe this variable is undefined.

Comment: @NimaEbrazeh It's a model.rb file, which I can click through to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to test:

```
:model-name="NewParticipant || ''"
```

If it does not throw error, your NewParticipant is `undefined`